# Null Array Query

Tags: powershell

Hopefully a really quick one, I've the following script and I've seen on a couple of instances that it prompts the following error:

```
Cannot index into a null array
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Scripts\Set-TeamsFirewallRules\Set-TeamsFirewallRules(PerUser).ps1:40 char:17
+ ...        If ($LastAccessTime[0].LastWriteTime -le $StaleAccountDate)
    + CategoryInfo            : InvalidOperation (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId   : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Scripts\Set-TeamsFirewallRules\Set-TeamsFirewallRules(PerUser).ps1:45 char:17
+ ...        If ($LastAccessTime[0].LastWriteTime -ge $StaleAccountDate)
    + CategoryInfo            : InvalidOperation (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId   : NullArray
```

The script is as follows:

```
# =========================== Log Template ==============================
$LogPath = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs'
$LogName = $LogPath + "\Set-TeamsFirewallRule.log"

If ((Test-Path $LogPath) -eq $false)
{
    New-Item -Path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs' -ItemType Directory
}
# =========================== Log Template ==============================

Start-Transcript -Path $LogName -Force

#Get all the user profiles that are on the system
$users = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path -Path $env:SystemDrive -ChildPath 'Users') -Exclude 'Public', 'Administrator','Help*','svc*','defaultuser*' 

#Generate a date code for accounts that have had activity in the last 40 days
$StaleAccountDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-40)

if ($null -ne $users) 
    {
    
    #Check for any firewall rules that block Teams access and disable them
    Write-Output "Checking for firewall rules that block Teams Access"
    $TeamsBlock = Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *Teams* | Where-Object {($_.action -eq "Block") -and ($_.Enabled -eq 'True')}

    If ($null -ne $TeamsBlock)
    {
        Foreach ($Rule in $TeamsBlock)
        {
            Write-Output "Disabling blocking firewall rule $($Rule.DisplayName)"
            Set-NetFirewallRule $Rule.Name -Enabled False
        }
    }

    foreach ($user in $users) 
        {
            #Check the last time something was written to the file path for the user we are checking
            $LastAccessTime = Get-ChildItem $user.FullName | sort lastwritetime -Descending

            If ($LastAccessTime[0].LastWriteTime -le $StaleAccountDate)
            {
                Write-Output "Skipping $($user.Name) because the last access time on the account is too old"
            }

            If ($LastAccessTime[0].LastWriteTime -ge $StaleAccountDate)
            {
                Write-Output "Checking $($user.FullName)"
                #Generate the path that will be checked
                $progPath = Join-Path -Path $user.FullName -ChildPath "AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Current\Teams.exe"
                    
                    if (Test-Path $progPath) 
                    {
                        #Check that the firewall rule already exists, if it does skip, if not, add it
                        $RuleCheck = Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter -Program $progPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                        if ($Null -eq $RuleCheck) 
                        {
                            Write-Output "Creating new firewall rules for $($user.Name)"
                            $ruleName = "Teams.exe for user $($user.Name)"
                            
                            #Here we add some things into the actual Rule name so that it is friendly and easily searchable.  We also want the rule name and display name to match.
                            "UDP", "TCP" | ForEach-Object { New-NetFirewallRule -Name ($RuleName + " " + $_.ToString()) -DisplayName ($RuleName + " " + $_.ToString()) -Direction Inbound -Profile Any -Program $progPath -Action Allow -Protocol $_ }
                            Clear-Variable ruleName
                        }

                        If ($Null -ne $RuleCheck)
                        {
                            Write-Output "Looks like there are already rules in place for $($user.Name) so we will not add any"
                        }
                    }

                    if ((Test-Path $progPath) -eq $false)
                    {
                        Write-Output "Looks like $($user.Name) has not launched Teams, we will be skipping"
                    }
            }
            
        #Clear the variables for the next user run
        Clear-Variable TeamsBlock
        Clear-Variable RuleCheck
        Clear-Variable progPath
            
    }
}



# =========================== Log Template ==============================
Stop-Transcript
# =========================== Log Template ==============================
```

Also, feel like I may have my Clear-Variable commands in the wrong place.

If anyone can help, it'd be greatly appreciated. I may need another If statement going in to say if it's $Null however, not fully sure where to add it.

Many thanks,

A

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward - `$LastAccessTime` doesn't contain anything, because the previous `Get-ChildItem $user.FullName` command doesn't return any files.

Comment: Thanks, where can I suppress the error if this is the case?

Comment: What do you want to do if no files are found? Just skip to the next user in the loop?

Comment: Yes pretty much, so if there's no writetime then skip on. Also just looking at the Clear-Variable's at the end, I think they're sitting outside of my loops.

Comment: Then it's easy - just add another if statement immediately after `$LastAccessTime = Get-ChildItem ...`: `if(-not $LastAccessTime) { continue }`

Comment: Thank you and re the Clear-Variable's at the end. Do they need moving up?

Comment: If `$LastAccessTime` is empty then the script never reach the point where they get valorized sp they stay `$null`. In fact, if anything, you might want to move clearing them OUTSIDE the `Foreach` if you really need to clear them up as they are never read before being re-valorized each loop, thus it's worthy to clear them only after they have been used for the last time. This applies to `$RuleName` as well

Comment: Hey, thanks for this :). So are you suggested to add themfurther down the script?

Comment: @Admaine I'd remove the `Clear-Variable` statements from the script completely, they're  entirely unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this would occur when `$LastAccessTime` doesn't contain any value - `$LastAccessTime[0]` is thus evaluated as `$null[0]`, hence the "null array" error message.

You can use the `continue` control flow keyword to skip to the next iteration of the loop:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
  $LastAccessTime = Get-ChildItem $user.FullName | ...

  if (-not $LastAccessTime.Count) {
    # skip process user if no files can be discovered
    continue
  }

  # <rest of loop body goes here>
}
```

Additionally, you can simplify the branching of your script by using `if`/`else` - instead of doing this:

```
if (Test-Path $path){
  # do something if path exists
}
if ((Test-Path $path) -eq $false) {
  # do something if path doesn't exist
}
```

... simply do:

```
if (Test-Path $path){
  # do something if path exists
}
else {
  # do something if path doesn't exist
}
```

---

> Also, feel like I may have my `Clear-Variable` commands in the wrong place.

My personal recommendation would be to remove the `Clear-Variable` statements entirely and to not worry about clearing variable contents manually at all - .NET is generally a memory-safe runtime, and all user-space memory is automatically tracked - meaning there's no need to guard against use-after-free (or similar memory-access-related) vulnerabilities.

If you insist on keeping them, move them to the "earliest" next call site after using the associated variable for the last time - ie. `Clear-Variable TeamsBlock` should be called immediately after the `if` block where it's last used:

```
If ($null -ne $TeamsBlock)
{
    Foreach ($Rule in $TeamsBlock)
    {
        Write-Output "Disabling blocking firewall rule $($Rule.DisplayName)"
        Set-NetFirewallRule $Rule.Name -Enabled False
    }
}

# we're done with $TeamsBlock at this point
Clear-Variable TeamsBlock
```

That being said, the construct `if($null -ne $collection){ foreach($item in $collection) { ... }}` is also unnecessary - the `foreach` loop statement will treat `$null` as an empty list, so `foreach($item in $null){ ... }` if entirely safe, as nothing happens:

```
foreach ($Rule in $TeamsBlock) {
  Write-Output "Disabling blocking firewall rule $($Rule.DisplayName)"
  Set-NetFirewallRule $Rule.Name -Enabled False
}

# we're done with $TeamsBlock at this point - if it's already $null this also won't do anything
Clear-Variable TeamsBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have rewritten some parts of your code with comment explaining the changes.

The reason of your error was probably your lack of Permission to access some User Directories, resulting in `Get-ChildItem` returning `$null` which, quite obviously, has no Properties.
Thus the error.

My code proposes two different solutions, depending on your specific use-case and details. You'll have to see what you find the best.
I also added assorted minor changes and, I hope, improvements in the code-flow, with enough comments to make it understandable

```
# =========================== Log Template ==============================
$LogPath = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs'
$LogName = $LogPath + '\Set-TeamsFirewallRule.log'

If (-not (Test-Path $LogPath)) {
    New-Item -Path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs' -ItemType Directory
}
# =========================== Log Template ==============================

Start-Transcript -Path $LogName -Force

# Get all the user profiles that are on the system
# We are interested only in the Sub-Directories, so -Directory skips whatever file might be there
$users = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path (Join-Path -Path $env:SystemDrive -ChildPath 'Users') -Exclude 'Public', 'Administrator', 'Help*', 'svc*', 'defaultuser*'

#Generate a date code for accounts that have had activity in the last 40 days
$StaleAccountDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-40)

# no need to check specifically for (not)$null
if ($users) {
            
    #Check for any firewall rules that block Teams access and disable them
    Write-Output 'Checking for firewall rules that block Teams Access'
    $TeamsBlock = Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *Teams* | Where-Object { ($_.action -eq 'Block') -and ($_.Enabled -eq 'True') }

    # no need to check $TeamBlock: if it's null the loop will be skipped
    Foreach ($Rule in $TeamsBlock) {
        Write-Output "Disabling blocking firewall rule $($Rule.DisplayName)"
        Set-NetFirewallRule $Rule.Name -Enabled False
    }
            

    foreach ($user in $users) {

        # Get the last time each directory was accessed
        $LastAccessTime = $user.LastAccessTime

        <#
        # as alternative: if you want to check the last time the files inside where accessed

        # get all files in the directtory, if don't have access silence the error(the result will be $Null)
        $LastAccessTime = Get-ChildItem -Path $user.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
            # sort them by LastAccessTime, in descending order from the most recent to the least recent
            Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | 
            # select the most recent and returns only the LastAccessTime value instead of the whole object
            Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty LastAccessTime

        # check if $LastAccessTime is $null, if so then skip to the next iteration
        # NOTE: this happens only if you do not have access to the directory and use the files-inside method
        if (-not $LastAccessTime) {
            continue 
        }
        
        #>

        # Compare values, now easier to write and understand
        If ($LastAccessTime -lt $StaleAccountDate) {
            Write-Output "Skipping $($user.Name) because the last access time on the account is too old"
        }
        # no need for a second IF as ELSE does the same
        else {
            Write-Output "Checking $($user.FullName)"
            #Generate the path that will be checked
            $progPath = Join-Path -Path $user.FullName -ChildPath 'AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Current\Teams.exe'
                            
            # check if $progPath exists
            if (Test-Path $progPath) {
                #Check that the firewall rule already exists, if it does skip, if not, add it
                $RuleCheck = Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter -Program $progPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                # check if $RuleChek is valorized
                If ($RuleCheck) {
                    Write-Output "Looks like there are already rules in place for $($user.Name) so we will not add any"
                }
                # no need for a second IF as ELSE does the same
                else {
                    Write-Output "Creating new firewall rules for $($user.Name)"
                    $ruleName = "Teams.exe for user $($user.Name)"
                                    
                    #Here we add some things into the actual Rule name so that it is friendly and easily searchable.  We also want the rule name and display name to match.
                    'UDP', 'TCP' | ForEach-Object -Process { New-NetFirewallRule -Name ($RuleName + ' ' + $_.ToString()) -DisplayName ($RuleName + ' ' + $_.ToString()) -Direction Inbound -Profile Any -Program $progPath -Action Allow -Protocol $_ }
                }

            }
            # no need for a second IF as ELSE does the same
            # if $progPath does not exist, warn the user
            else {
                Write-Output "Looks like $($user.Name) has not launched Teams, we will be skipping"
            }
        }
    }

    # if you really NEED to manually clean-up the variables, here's the place
    # but in this specific scenario it's completely useless, so have them commented off.
    # Clear-Variable ruleName
    # Clear-Variable TeamsBlock
    # Clear-Variable RuleCheck
    # Clear-Variable progPath
}



# =========================== Log Template ==============================
Stop-Transcript
# =========================== Log Template ==============================
```

Comment: this is amazing thank you :) couple of quick questions. Re `$user.LastAccessTime`, does this refer to the last sign in time, or could it mean the last time a users directories were accessed? Secondly, should `if (-not $LastAccessTime) {
            continue 
        }` be uncommented? Thank you

Comment: also noticed that when I run this, it doesn't seem to run the "Skipping $($user.Name) because the last access time on the account is too old" on accounts older than 40 days.

Comment: I tweaked to allow `Lastwritetime` but it added for rules for an account who's last write time was 11/07/2023?

Comment: Generally speaking: your question has been technically answered and you should post a new one with the new problems.   That said:   `LastAccessTime` is the last time a file or directory was OPENED by anybody(included you checking it out). I am honestly unsure if just logging in would apply any change to the files in a user's home directory. Checking `-not $LastAccessTime` is to avoid errors if you don't have access to the files inside the user directories. But anybody should have read-access to the properties of the directory itself, making it useless if you are checking only it.

Comment: thanks, so `-not $LastAccessTime` should remain commented out, as it's only required if using the `Lastwritetime` ?

Comment: `-not $LastAccessTime` is necessary and should be uncommented ONLY if you are using `Get-ChildItem` to get its value. That's why I block-commented them together.